# Unique login for multiple clients in KeyCloak

Tags: keycloak

In Keycloak, is it possible to have only one login for all the clients in the same realms? I have configured the server (from the admin console) in this way:
- create a new realm (let's call MyRealm);
- create two different clients (Client1 and Client2) 
- create a user (Alice) 
I have tested the two clients individually, and they works fine (the default keycloak login page appear and if I provide the credentials the browser redirects me correctly); the problem is that when I am logged in in Client1, and go (from the same browser) to Client2 the login page re-appers. Is it possible to configure the server in a way that I have to log in only with one client, and then I am authenticated also in all other Realm's clients? Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve that using frontend authentication (JS adapter).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem configuring only one client (named UniqueClient) from Keycloak admin console; then I modified the two java applications (Client1 and Client2) and now all of them are pointing to UniqueClient (in their keycloak.json there is **'clientId': 'UniqueClient'**): in this way when I start one of them the keycloak login page appears, and if I log in, I'm logged in also for the other application (unitil the session expires);

Comment: Is there any security risks associated with the above aproach https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/single-client-configuration-for-multiple-applications/2053

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki so you will be logged in several clients at the same time on the same realm